# Importing CSV file to MySQL with python

Tags: python, mysql, csv, import

I don't know what am I doing wrong here. I have already tried sevral codes but still I am not able to import the csv file to MySQL with python.[I have attached the screenshot off the error message I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8bh2.png)

Here is the code

```
    pip install sqlalchemy

    pip install mysqlclient pymysql

    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    import pandas as pd
    df=pd.read_csv("olympix.csv")
    db_connection_str='mysql+pymysql://root:Shubh@123/olympix'
    db_connection=create_engine(db_connection_str)
    print(df)
    df.to_sql('olympix',db_connection)
```

Comment: Where is your MySQL running?  What you have there is trying to access a server on a machine called "123", with username "root" and password "Shubh".  Is the server running on your local machine?

Comment: Yes MYSQL is also running. And Shubh@123 is the password.

Comment: Then you have made a poor choice of password.  Choose one that does not have `:` or `@` and add `@localhost`.

Comment: Please [edit] your question so that it does not contain [images of error messages](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: I changed the password, it is still not working :(                                                       from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("olympix.csv")
db_connection_str='mysql+pymysql://root:mypass@localhost:3306/olympix'
db_connection=create_engine(db_connection_str)
print(df)
df.to_sql('olympix',db_connection)

Comment: Getting this error now:  OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

OperationalError                          Traceback (most recent call last)
OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")
OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' ([Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address)")

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the problem is in your connection string. Are you sure 123 is the host that's running your database??

Your connection string must be in this format: dialect+driver://username:password@host:port/database